# Date field in FormAPI, remove Day field?

Tags: 7, forms

Using a 'date' field in the FormAPI, is there something I can set to hide the day field from showing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a setting for that, but you could do it with the `#after_build` option, as it will allow you to alter the form element after it has been processed (day, month and year fields have been created).

Answer (score 2):

I think you could accomplish this using the widgets provided by the [Date module](http://drupal.org/project/date), specifically the `date_text` widget:

```
$form['date'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date_text',
  '#title' => 'Date',
  '#date_format' => 'm/Y',
  '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d')
);
```

You can use the `#date_format` key to set the level of granularity you want for the element date.

Be aware the default value has to be in the `Y-m-d` format for some reason (can't dig out the link to the issue on drupal.org at the moment but I'll update the answer if I find it).

Comment: date_default_date() in date_api_elements.inc requires that the element has a default value.  `date('Y-m')` works for this case as well, although any value longer than the "granularity" requires works.

Comment: Very little on the internet for this problem, which must be an incredibly common use case.  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code example, close to the op request that may help other devs. Based on the answer by @Clive

```
$form['deadline'] = array(
  '#title' => 'Deadline ',
  '#type' => 'date_select',
  '#date_title' => 'Deadline',
  '#date_format' => 'm/Y',
  '#date_year_range' => '0:+1',
  '#default_value' => variable_get('deadline', date('Y-m')),
  '#description' => t('Deadline description'),
);
```

If you use this instead of the form api date type element, then the value is stored differently.  The form api date element is like this:

```
array(
  'year' => 2013, 
  'month' => 12,
  'day' => 31,
);
```

Whereas the date_select form element is stored as a string:

```
"2013-12-31"
```

Although for the example above the value is formatted like this:

```
"2013-12"
```

So you'll need to adjust the areas of your site that use this data.